# How to convert decimal into integer in a sentence of character in C#?

Tags: c#, string, integer

**Example:***

```
string str = "i have rs 12.55"
```

and I want to print this as

```
"i have rs 12"
```

while *ignoring* `.55` in sentence.

Comment: Post what you have tried

Comment: So you would want "i have rs 12.99999" to come out as "i have rs 12"? Not "i have rs 13"?

Comment: That duplicate is not a duplicate... it will really not help with the more difficult part of parsing the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with string function `Substring` and capture the string till `.`

```
string str = "i have rs 12.55";
var result = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('.'));
```

> However, I suggest to remove the decimal part from `12.55` before forming the string.

```
double value = 12.55;
string str = $"i have rs {(int)value}";
```

OR

```
decimal value = 12.55M;
string str = $"i have rs {decimal.Truncate(value)}";
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove *all* fractional parts, you can try *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

... 

Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=[0-9]+)\.[0-9]+");

string result = regex.Replace(str, "");
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "i have rs 12.55",
    "I have rs 12.55 and -8.63 but 0.78963",
    "list : A.B.C.D",
    "12 - 45... but 78.99"
  };

  Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=[0-9]+)\.[0-9]+");

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-40} => {regex.Replace(test, "")}")) ;

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
i have rs 12.55                          => i have rs 12
I have rs 12.55 and -8.63 but 0.78963    => I have rs 12 and -8 but 0
list : A.B.C.D                           => list : A.B.C.D
12 - 45... but 78.99                     => 12 - 45... but 78
```